# How do I get the position of individual characters rendered on user's browsers? (Jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p> this is a very long text indeed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
```

When I render the sample text on the web, the position of each characters change based on user's settings. (For example, the line divisions are different based on which browser the user is using, and how much is the page magnified  - zoom in any webpage with lots of texts and you'll see this changes a lot)

But the application I'm trying to make has to get the position of individual characters to work.
So I need the position relative to the entire webpage and/or some other position (such as the position relative to the starting point of the paragraph.)

BTW, I prefer Jquery solution...but if you can't do it with Jquery, I'm OK with solutions using other libraries/tools

Thank you :)

p.s:sorry for my bad English... if you don't get the question, it's probably my fault.

---

I got the idea of using the span tag and the .offset()  - thank you for the quick solutions:)

But I wonder if there's another way than using the span tag...maybe somekind of empty tag that does nothing but contain a character or more...

Is this possible if I use CSS or some other stuff?

anyway, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using the above mentioned HTML. You can get the position of the `<p>` element using [**`.offset()`**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method. But you will not be able to get the position of individual characters unless you are placing them in seperate containers, which I think will not be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Umm this is not a great solution, but... maybe if you broke up the text into individual tags, this would work? E.g.

```
<p> this is a very long text indeed.</p>
```

becomes, via JavaScript,

```
<p id="para1">
    <span> </span>
    <span class="word"><span>t</span><span>h</span><span>i</span><span>s</span></span>
    <span> </span>
    <span class="word"><span>i</span><span>s</span>
    <span> </span>
    ...
</p>
```

Then you could use CSS to make sure it doesn't break in the middle of your new "words":

```
span.word { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Then you could get the position of the nth character with something like

```
var characters = $("#para1 span:not(.word)");
var nthPosition = characters.eq(n).offset();
```

Here `n` is zero-based, so in the above ' ' is the 0th character and 't' is the first.

Comment: I tried the solution with <span> tag... but this solution changes the width of the text - which is not what I wanted. (or maybe my firefox is doing the wrong job...) But anyway, thanks for giving me the idea  :)

Comment: Hmm. Did you make sure there is no whitespace in between the `</span>` and `<span>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a textual answer to what you can do, but it will require much work to be a cross-browser implementation, and I don't know enough of the details to provide workable code.

First you select the character that you're after (I assume a range object will be needed, or some text searching of the contents of the paragraph):

Lore**m** ipsum dolor sit amet.

Then you surround it with a span:

Lore<span>m</span> ipsum dolor sit amet

Then you select the span and check it's offset:

`var spanOffset = $('span').offset();`

of course, you're going to probably want to add a class to the span, and make sure that it has the most neutral styles possible.